# "Aforementioned" vs. "aforesaid"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives

I'm writing a paper. In it, I have the following sentence.

> The ****_*__*_*____*** principle has two discrepancies.

I am considering using either "[aforementioned](http://0-www.oed.com.iii.slcl.org/view/Entry/317604)" or "[aforesaid](http://0-www.oed.com.iii.slcl.org/view/Entry/317603)". How are the meaning of the two different? The definition for "aforesaid" is

> Stated or mentioned before; aforementioned.

The definition of "aforementioned" is

> Previously mentioned, esp. in a text.

Are their meanings different? When should I use which?

Comment: You have "aforestated" in your title, but in the question you mention "aforementioned" and "aforesaid." I'd use "aforementioned in a paper, though I can't tell you why.

Comment: I'd probably choose *aforementioned* in that case, and it seems this is [increasingly becoming the popular choice](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aforesaid+principle%2Caforementioned+principle&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @Jim: That Ngram uses the word "principle", but that's probably not a good way to really see how often the words are used. After all, there could be an aforementioned theorum, an aforementioned axiom, an aforementioned [lemma](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&prmdo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22aforementioned+lemma%22&oq=%22aforementioned+lemma%22&gs_l=serp.3...2438930.2442262.2.2442477.20.19.0.0.0.4.126.1847.11j8.19.0...0.0...1c.1.UDYulBpeZDM&pbx=1&prmdo=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=5025d1f0ac3082a6&bpcl=37189454&biw=1554&bih=863), etc.

Comment: @J.R.- yes, it was not my intent to see how *aforementioned* was used in general, but rather how it was used with *principle*.  I felt that coupling it might help eliminate some of the other forms/phrases that might creep in in a more general search.  If my intention was to compare relative frequencies of use, you are correct that adding *principle* would not be the way to do that.

Comment: Can someone explain the close votes? This is not general reference. I clearly stated what I had already found out. My question was when should I use which? It cannot be answered with one link to a standard internet source.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just say "this principle ..." instead of "the aforementioned principle ..."?  It's kind of what "this" means.

Comment: Luke: I voted to close, simply because the words are synonymous, and you could use either one, although you run a risk of having the language sound overly stodgy or overly technical. Not much else needs to be said. Note that I did _not_ downvote, because I thought your question was well-formed, well-researched, and well-presented. Also, I voted to close only _after_ you had received some helpful answers. Had you focused more on the "when should I use which?" part, I may have read it differently, but you did ask "How are they different?" – twice – when clearly their meanings don't differ much.

Comment: @DavidWallace Because in the previous two sentences, I had name two different principles. "This" would either be ambiguous or refer to the latter.

Comment: @Luke: 'Aforementioned' would be ambiguous also. The 'latter' or 'former' principle would not. 'Aforementioned isn't exactly archaic, but it is very noticeably pretentious sounding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They make you sound like a lawyer, and I wouldn’t use either. Try *The principle (I have) already mentioned* or *The principle referred to above.*

Comment: It depends on the context, I think. I've seen _aforementioned_ rather often, particularly in proofs, or in papers where one principle keeps building upon another. Your suggestions are good for those times when you only need to refer to something _previously mentioned_ once or twice, but _aforementioned_ can be a concise way to say it if you need to express that notion several times throughout a scientific paper.

Answer (score 3):

I find the supercited *aforementioned* to be way too complicated.  It tends to raise eyebrows, and not just superciliously, either.  More like supersilliest, perhaps.

You could just call it the *stated principle*, or  (unless this form bothers you too much), the *above principle*.

Just don’t use *supercited*. :)

Answer (score 2):

*said* implies speech.

If one points out "but that was written and not said" in case you use a speech-related expression in relation to a text, it's pointless nitpicking, but it's the kind of nitpicking easily avoided by using a generic, non-speech-related expression like *mentioned* instead.