# Is 'aforementioned' suitable in a science paper?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Is the word 'aforementioned' suitable in a science paper?

> It appears from the aforementioned investigations that ...

Comment: Eminently avoidable. It's bureaucratese, not technical.

Comment: You've used the term *balabala* in all three questions you've asked so far. (In fact, I thought this was a duplicate because of it, until I checked.) It's not a normal word, and it looks bizarre. I suggest that if you want to represent filler in a sentence, you simply use the more normal ellipses:  . . .

Comment: Sorry for the bizarre look. I'll modify these questions. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: I thought the OP meant to use "blahblahblah" meaning "not formal". It would suggest that the context might be as discussion or less formal "filler" within an otherwise technical scientific paper. Science papers do have different sections with varying degrees of technical aspect. I would think "aforementioned" could be used effectively as "less formal but acceptable" language.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've seen many similar questions in this forum, and see many answers about it's 'legal document' use only. Thus, I wonder if this word can be used in a science paper. As Kris commented before, is this word bureaucratese?

Comment: There's no reason that its usage should be restricted to legal documents: it can be used in other types of documents. But (in my view) "the previously mentioned investigations"; or "the investigations previously mentioned"; or "the investigations mentioned above" are all better alternatives (in British English).

Comment: it’s just interesting to note that *balabala* can be pronounced identically to *blah blah*

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'suitable' here? The word would be readily understood, and its use is grammatically OK. Whether it fits the style of a paper in a particular discipline is a discipline-specific question, and is likely to be a matter of opinion even among those who specialise in that discipline. It is thus not something to which one can expect to receive a definite answer on a site of this kind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is using the term "aforementioned" sometimes considered bad practice?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/348011/is-using-the-term-aforementioned-sometimes-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I frequently use 'aformentioned', its a quick an easy way to say 'previously mentioned' or 'as discussed above', as long as it matches the rest of your writing to

Comment: Is this word bureaucratese and used in legal documents only as [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90013/338073)?

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

A previous comment suggests aforementioned is too bureaucratic. I disagree. It is a precise term that in this context means “all the relevant material that was written down in this paper previously”. Precise enough for a legal document or scientific paper.

Comment: "[I]n this context" it does NOT mean "**all** the relevant material that was written down  ... previously":  it refers ONLY to the "investigations" mentioned previously.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Feel free to edit your answer if you wish to.

Comment: I get your reticence with the inclusion of “all” and I think I agree I may have overstated it. Perhaps I should have said something more like: aforementioned here means that this investigation that is now being referred to in this sentence has been mentioned earlier in this paper so if you have skipped ahead and this is the first you’ve read about this thing, and are in need of possible clarification, try going back a bit and you’ll probably get more info. Maybe not perfectly precise. But still, a pretty succinct (if long) word that is clear enough to appear in legal and scientific documents.

Comment: Naaah. I’ll leave it as is. Makes a nice little thread showing we can sometimes improve our answers with a little help Cheers. (Although I did have to change “answer” to “comment” and fix my pathetic spelling - and veto autocorrect changing naaah to Nash right here in this comment, lol)

Comment: Wrong. *Wrong.*